DESeq2 Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value): Invalid 'row.names' length
I am new to RNAseq and started to analyze my dataset using DESeq2. I first run the DESeqDataSetFromMatrix function and found the error message Error in DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = HitCount, colData = myCondition,  :  ncol(countData) == nrow(colData) is not TRUE
In addition, if I run the following code I get this warning:
all(colnames(HitCount) == myCondition$SampleID)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In colnames(HitCount) == myCondition$SampleID :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I then searched online and arranged my code as follow:
myCondition <- read_excel("ConditionTable.xlsx")
View(myCondition)
head(myCondition)

HitCount <- read_excel("HitCounts_30mpi.xlsx", col_names = TRUE,
                       col_types = c("text", "numeric", "numeric",
                                     "numeric", "numeric", "numeric",
                                     "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                     "numeric"))
View(HitCount)
head(HitCount)
rownames(HitCount) <- HitCount[,1]
HitCount <- HitCount[,-1]
head(HitCount)

all(colnames(HitCount) == myCondition$SampleID)

str(HitCount)

dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = HitCount,
                              colData = myCondition,
                              design = ~ Condition)

dds <- DESeq(dds)

However, I do get the following error when running rownames(HitCount) <- HitCount[,1]:
Error in .rowNamesDF<-(x, value = value) :
invalid lenght in 'row.names' `
This does not stop R to in the calculation but I get in my results that the row names are changed in numbers. Do you know how I can keep the original row names and having DESeqDataSetFromMatrix TRUE?
This is a piece of my excel file:
Gene_ID    CTRL_1 CTRL_2 CTRL_3 SXM_1 SXM_2 SXM_3 XS_1 XS_2 XS_3  
VDAG_00XX1 661 558 555 509 325 338 526 611 419 2 
VDAG_00XX2 1920 1545 1457 2033 1160 1231 1691 1689 1496 3 
VDAG_00XX3 568 568 514 946 718 728 1805 1920 1549 4 
VDAG_00XX4 6774 6676 7036 5335 4079 3917 8557 9658 7973


head(dput(count_matrix)) read the data to R studio and then dput as there might be issue with excel format

I did actually solve the problem in a more unorthodox way. I just saved my excel file as .csv and them read the data with 'read.csv'. After that, the same line of commands worked out just fine.

yes most of the time xls are issue
